# Delete based on column values when it is part of a composite key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has an id and a date. (id, date) make up the composite key for the table.

What I am trying to do is delete all entries older than a specific date.

```
delete from my_table where date < '2018-12-12'
```

The query plan explains that it will do a sequential scan for the date column.

I somehow want to make use of the index present since the number of distinct ids are very very small compared to total rows in the table.

How do I do it ? I have tried searching for it but to no avail

Comment: Is your use-case some sort of data archival or data deletion when certain period of time has passed?

Comment: @swayamraina Yes correct

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: felt like it was not specific to a product, hence the missing specific tag. I am trying to do this on psql though, so have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your use-case involves data-archival on monthly basis or some time period, you can think of updating your DataBase table to use partitions.

Let's say you collect data on monthly basis and want to keep data for the last 5 months. It would be really efficient to create partition over the table based on month of the year.

This will,

- optimise your READ queries (table scans will reduce to partition scans)
- optimise your DELETE requests (just delete the complete partition)

Comment: I have thought about doing this, looks like this is what I will end up doing

Comment: This seems the best solution unless you can think off a new use case which involves archival based on some variable number of days. In that case, partitioning won't help.

Comment: If you think this is the answer to t he problem, you can accept this answer for others to refer this in future.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on `date` for this query:

```
create index idx_mytable_date on mytable(date);
```

Alternatively, you can drop your existing index and add a new one with `(date, id)`.  `date` needs to be the first key for this query.

Comment: I think creating an additional index for this sole purpose does not make a lot of sense. Also, the existing index is created with the type of data in mind.

Comment: @vishalv2050 . . . Well, your existing index cannot be used for this query.

Comment: I think in the worst case, I can go over the list of unique ids and do the deletion for each of then individually. I was hoping for something smarter than that. The number of unique ids are far far lesser as compared to the total rows